# a question about conjunction logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Let's take this question as an example:

> prove that a finite group is the union of proper subgroups if and only if the group is not cyclic.

Then we prove that If

1. G is the union of proper subgroups
2. G is simutaneously a cyclic group

Then we would have a contradiction, in other words, G cannot be simutaneously both a union of proper subgroups and cyclic.

What I want to ask is, after this contradiction, aren't we have already proved the pervious statement? since If G is indeed a union of proper subgroups, then G must not by cyclic, and if G is indeed cyclic, then G must not be a union of proper subgroups.

Or, that this contradiction  only proved this argument only in one direction, and says nothing at all in another direction?

Comment: Sorry that I speak poor English, If there is any confusing part,  feel free to comment or to edit.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, try rephrasing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let G be a finite group.

Let A be the proposition that $A :=$ G is a union of proper subgroups. 
Let B be the proposition that $B :=$ G is not cyclic.

You want to prove that $A \Longleftrightarrow B $

What you are doing is to prove $A \land \lnot B \implies \bot$, that is equivalent to proving $\lnot (A \land \lnot B)$, which is equivalent to proving  $\lnot A \lor B$ which is equivalent to proving  $A \implies B$ .

So you're proving only one direction of the statement. You also need to prove  $B \implies A$, that is the contradiction $B \land \lnot A \implies \bot$.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument would show that no group can be both cyclic and also the union of proper subgroups. That's not enough, however, as the problem asks you to prove that *any* group has *exactly one* of those two properties, not just that no group has both properties.

I would instead do it by proving the following two statements:

- A cyclic group is not the union of proper subgroups. Specifically, there are elements in the group such that no proper subgroup contains those elements. (Hint: what are the "special" elements that cyclic groups have that other groups don't?)
- A non-cyclic group is the union of proper subgroups. Specifically, in a non-cyclic group, each and every element lies in at least one proper subgroup, and you can take the union of those. (Hint: a cyclic subgroup must be proper.)